# Read List item including attachments CSOM Powershell - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom

I am trying to read list item and the attachments from SharePoint 2010 using CSOM Powershell.

But I keep getting below error message `Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Field or property "AttachmentFiles" does not exist."`

I tested same code for SharePoint Online and It works perfectly there.

Below is the code:

```
$web = $context.web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("CR_Temporary")

$item = $list.GetItemById(18)
$context.load($item);
$context.ExecuteQuery()


$AttachmentsColl = $item.AttachmentFiles
$context.Load($AttachmentsColl)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

ForEach($Attachment in $AttachmentsColl)
{
    $AttachmentCreation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AttachmentCreationInformation               
}
```

Am I missing something here? Please guide me...

Thanks

Comment: Try using `$item.Attachments`.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I tried. But I am getting `Cannot find an overload for "load" and the argument count: "1".`

Comment: Check [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-add-attachment-to-list-item-using-powershell.html) and [this](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/08/get-sharepoint-list-item-attachments.html) maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code snippet below for "CR_Temporary" list and Item Id "1":

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'

$site = 'http://sp/sites/dev'
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
$web = $context.web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("CR_Temporary")

$item = $list.GetItemById(1)
$context.load($item);
$context.ExecuteQuery()


$AttachmentsColl = $item.AttachmentFiles
$context.Load($AttachmentsColl)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

ForEach($Attachment in $AttachmentsColl)
{
   Write-Host("File Name - " + $Attachment.FileName);       
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you testing this code for SharePoint 2010 ?  For me this code works in SharePoint Online But I am facing issue in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Yes, tested in SharePoint Server 2010

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful.